# Installing FuelPHP using cURL not working

Tags: php, shell, curl, fuelphp

I'm trying to install FuelPHP on my system using the following command:

```
curl get.fuelphp.com/oil | sh
```

but the output I get from that is:

```
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2301  100  2301    0     0     18      0  0:02:07  0:02:03  0:00:04   576
sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Have tried it on several different machines, always the same result.

Anything I'm doing wrong? (Other than tagging this as being related to PHP, apparently)

Comment: How the question is related to php?

Comment: FuelPHP is a PHP framework...

Comment: so what? You have the issues with linux shell, don't you? I see, that `sh` throws a error, not php. Have you tried to see what actually you've downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the URL : `get.fuelphp.com/oil` 
(1) it is missing the http part
(2) it is non existent or broken

See for yourself:
http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fget.fuelphp.com%2Foil
http://snag.gy/5OBR6.jpg

or maybe you meant `fuelphp.com/oil` but that url doesnt work either.

Edit: I now see what you are trying to do as per http://docs.fuelphp.com/ but maybe their little installer is broken?

Comment: Looks like it was just down. Seems fine now! Thanks!